# doctrine:schema:update is not updating table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Why `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` is not updating database table?

This is an entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="country")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CoreBundle\Repository\CountryRepository")
 */
class Country
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $active;

    ....
    }
```

The table `country` was created, but there is only `id` column. 
I keep getting `Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.` but `name` and `active` columns are not added

I am adding Doctrine Configuration too

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

**UPDATE**

Problem was in Redis. If I remove doctrine caching configurations from config.yml, everything works fine

Comment: The `name="foobar"` annotation parameter is redundant here, as Doctrine will use class names as table names and property names as column names by default.

Comment: Have you tried `app/console clear:cache`?

Comment: @lxg yes, still same. no updates in table

Answer (score 5):

`bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` command solved problem, table was updated